# How do I get a value from a dictionary when the key is a value in another dictionary in Lua?

Tags: dictionary, lua

I am writing some code where I have multiple dictionaries for my data. The reason being, I have multiple core objects and multiple smaller assets and the user must be able to choose a smaller asset and have some function off in the distance run the code with the parent noted.

An example of one of the dictionaries: (I'm working in ROBLOX Lua 5.1 but the syntax for the problem should be identical)

```
local data = {
    character = workspace.Stores.NPCs.Thom,
    name = "Thom", npcId = 9,
    npcDialog = workspace.Stores.NPCs.Thom.Dialog
}
local items = {
    item1 = {
        model = workspace.Stores.Items.Item1.Main,
        npcName = "Thom",
    }
}
```

This is my function:

```
local function function1(item)
    if not items[item] and data[items[item[npcName]]] then return false end
end
```

As you can see, I try to index the dictionary using a key from another dictionary. Usually this is no problem.

```
local thisIsAVariable = item[item1[npcName]]
```

but the method I use above tries to index the data dictionary for data that is in the items dictionary.

Without a ton of local variables and clutter, is there a way to do this? I had an idea to wrap the conflicting dictionary reference in a tostring() function to separate them - would that work?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, first of all, you don't have an `items` table in your data table. Second, I may be wrong here, but it seems like you'd need to make the tables global and use the `_G` table to access everything correctly.

Comment: @Josh, you are mistaken. `t = {a = "Here", b = "I", c = "am"} t2 = {"a", "b", "c"} print(t[t2[3]])` will print the word “am”. You can always use a table value as a key in another table. No need for _G.

Comment: @Brian Well, I was referring to the function call for `item`. I know `print(t[t2[3]])` would work in your example, but if I do `local item = "t2"`, then `print(t[item[3]])` wouldn't work. At least, it's been my experience it doesn't.

Comment: @Brian, Re, "You can always use a table value as a key..." IMO it would be better to say that there is _no such thing_ as a "table value." There's just values. The fact that some value can be found in a table somewhere has no bearing on where else or how else that same value may be used.

Comment: @jameslarge Agreed - "table value" is a bit inaccurate. `t2` is the table, `3` is the key, and `c` is the value. Now, that value `c` can be used as a key in table `t`. I am sure we agree on what's happening - we are just clarifying semantics a bit...which is okay.

Comment: It is unclear what are the values are that you want to get from the table in your function - Likely some of the variables you use when indexing should actually be string literals though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, your issue is that:

```
data[items[item[npcName]]]
```

is looking for data[“Thom”] ... but you do not have such a key in the data table. You have a “name” key that has a “Thom” value. You could reverse  the name key and value in the data table. “Thom” = name